# Impossible to get results from last year in twitter API search

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm new to the twitter API, and I was trying some very simple requests, and it seems that it is impossible to get last year's results. I'm using the TwitterOAuth library from Abraham Williams (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth).
This request gives me results

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("search/tweets", array('q'=>'from:RToVR until:2016-07-19'));
```

But this one doesn't:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("search/tweets", array('q'=>'from:RToVR until:2015-07-19'));
```

Anyone would have an idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, quite a simple answer. The Twitter Search API docs  https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search make clear that you can only retrieve about 7 days back programmatically as the index only covers that period.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this line, thanks! So is there an other way to retrieve older tweets via the web? I'd like to get all images from an user posted in 2015, but not sure it's possible...

Comment: The web search page would let you do that but it would be a very manual process, and you would have to page through the results (scraping is not allowed). The commercial GNIP products from Twitter provide fully-supported full-archive search, but that's not an inexpensive option.

Comment: OK, thanks for point this out. I'll change my project's behavior then, thanks!